# Is there a way to find out the revision number of the previous local revision prior to the last update?

Tags: svn, version-control

More specifically, I've just done an SVN update, but I liked my previous local revision better. Is there any way to query SVN to find out what the revision number of the previous local revision is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, svn is a tool to track your changes on the server, not on your working folder. As a result, I do not think you could do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no.